# release code uses large amount of memory not seen at design time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, memory-management, citrix

We have a WinForms application that's just been deployed as a 64bit build (64bit not any cpu) built on .NET4/vs2012.

When deploying onto citrix the server team have advised that one form take 30+ seconds to open and uses nearly 500mb of memory. Once opened and displayed the memory is released back and the application is then just using around 30mb.

I ran this code on my local machine and it exhibits the same behaviour.

If I then close the form and reopen it it's instantaneous.

The form isn't going off and doing anything strange - it's the huge amount of memory that's baffling.

However, if I run the code in visual studio it doesn't do this. The form shows pretty much instantly.

I've stepped through the code and it's doing nothing unusual as far as I can see. It's not making any calls to the database which I thought could be causing a problem or trying to access external services or anything odd.

If it just did it under citrix I'd think there was something going on there, but its also doing it my local machine (Windows 7 x64 pro)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: 500mb is very little memory. What makes you think that the memory usage is related to the performane problem?

Comment: I'd guess that it needs to load all needed assemblies which are loaded already when application is hosted by VS. Opening a form for 30+ seconds is strange, however as @JohnSaunders pointed out it doesn't have to be related with the performance. Please try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), otherwise it will be very hard to guess what's the problem.

Comment: I've run a debug 64bit version as well and it's only the release 64bit version that takes this massive amount of extra time and large amount of memory. 500mb is large compared to the applications usual footprint around 30-40mb. CPU hits around 25% for the time it's doing it as well.

Comment: I've run Ants Profile against the 64bit release exe.
This is the line that's taking up all the processor time...

Private drugsTable As DataTable = Nothing

Why on earth would this take 85% of the processor time? 

(It's just a type of System.Data.DataTable)

Comment: If I change that line to just Private drugsTable as DataTable with no initialiser then it just sits and hangs at the next line that has got one. The profiler doesn't show that it's then sitting and waiting doing stuff in the Form Initialise routine, just at that variable declaration line. The form has a whole heap of infragistics controls and other similar nightmarish things (11 ultragrids, 7 ultratabs as well as a myriad of other controls). What I don't get is why it's not hanging in design mode but takes 20-30 seconds at runtime.

Comment: We *think* that the problem here might be because the first time it goes into the form in question it's actually loading a new module for the first time, so it's gone from the main UI.exe to a UI.dll for the first time. So we think it's how the release is complied - it's in effect compiling the other UI module so we really need to build our release code with the additional command line switches to tell it to not allow the JIT building but a proper full build. But can I find the references for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with a moderately complicated WinForms program on NET4.5/VS2013. It loads virtually instantaneously in the DevEnv, but when run from the exe it takes ~60 seconds to load. During that time, it garners ~1.2GB of memory and consumes ~15% CPU resources. After loading, it's memory consumption drops to ~22 MB. If I check the "Prefer 32 Bit" option on the Compile Options page (using AnyCPU for Target CPU), the problem goes away and the executable loads very quickly. I am not sure why this is so, but hey it works!